# Do two array_aggs in a query share the same window?

Tags: postgresql, array-agg

Consider this example:

```
SELECT    comment_date
        , array_agg(user_id) users
        , array_agg(comment) comments
FROM      user_comments
GROUP BY  comment_date
```

1. Is it safe to assume that the indexes of *users* and *comments* refer to the same record (e.g., users[3] created comments[3])?
2. Is it possible that the order of the two arrays may refer to different records, possibly due to performance enhancements?

I don't know enough about the internals of Postgres to trust array_agg ordering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you explicitly specify it, you cannot assume **anything** about the order an aggregate function is applied. If you want to ensure that two calls to `array_agg` have corresponding values you should add the `order by` clause to both of them. E.g.:

```
SELECT    date
        , array_agg(user_id ORDER BY user_id) users
        , array_agg(comment ORDER BY user_id) comments
FROM      user_comments
GROUP BY  date
```

Comment: Do you know this for certain?  The query planner doesn't see two *array_agg*s and populate both when looking at the record?

Comment: It may (and probably should), but nowhere in postgres' documentation is there any guarantee of this. In my book, if it's not guaranteed at that level it means it may very well be changed for some optimization, so I wouldn't write code that assumes this.